# How to add button to the SB Admin 2 Card header without changing the height of the header?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using the amazing [SB Admin 2 template](https://startbootstrap.com/themes/sb-admin-2/) in my project and I am currently struggling in adding a button in the card header without expanding or changing the default height of the header as shown in the following snapshot:

[image]

I want the header of the right card to be the same as header of the other card on the left. **Could you please show me how to do that?** I am using the default CSS of the template.

Here's the HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Revenue Sources</h6>
                    <div class="dropdown no-arrow">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-sm fa-fw text-gray-400"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--fade-in" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                            <div class="dropdown-header">Dropdown Header:</div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Card Body -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5">
            <div class="card shadow mb-4">
                <!-- Card Header - Dropdown -->
                <div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Revenue Sources</h6>
                    <input name="btnView" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="cphBody_btnView" type="submit" value="View">
                </div>
                <!-- Card Body -->
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace this line with button like this.

```html
not use this =  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-sm fa-fw text-gray-400"></i>

use this = <button> my content  </button>
```